# .net core : google authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, google-authentication

I wanted to implement google authentication using .net core/angular7.
I works very well using http url address, however it did not work when i change the backend address to a secure domain https.

[image: result when calling google api]

Answer (score 1):

When your browser redirects the user to Google's authentication page, you will pass a  redirect URI parameter you want Google's server to return to your application with the token response . The redirect url should list in allowed `Authorized redirect URIs` in Google Console .

You can use Fiddler or browser's develop tools to trace the OAuth/OpenID connect request, find the redirect url and make sure that url is listed in `Authorized redirect URIs` in Google develop console .